# How do I get a list of tweets TO an account?

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I haven't found this exact use case on any other questions.

I want to get a list of tweets TO: an account.. The example here is @Azure.
How do I filter out re-tweets etc?

At the moment I am getting a list of tweets back that are not all messages to @Azure. Also some are retweets. Thanks :)

```
# Importing TWEEPY Library
import tweepy

# Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API
ACCESS_KEY = '*****'
ACCESS_SECRET = '*****'
CONSUMER_KEY = '*****'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '*****'

auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
search_results = api.search(q="@Azure", count=100)

for i in search_results:
    # Do Whatever You need to print here
    print(i.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP wants to exclude tweets that end up in the list of tweets but are actually a retweet.
Retweeted tweets that get to this list can be filtered by looking at the attribute 'retweeted_status'. If this is available and has its own attribute of status then it is definitely an RT.

I could check for this in PHP like below:

```
//Whatever code/library gets you a list of statuses, I use Abraham twitter oauth library

$params = [
    'q' => '@azure',
    'count'=>100,
    'exclude_replies' => 1 //exclude replies if you want
];
$statuses = $connection->get('search/tweets', $params);

foreach($statuses->statuses as $status){
    if($status->retweeted_status && $status->retweeted_status->text != ''){
        echo 'retweeted status';
    else
        echo 'not a retweeted status';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do i.retweet_count it should give you number of retweets of that post so you could maybe add

```
for i in search_results:
    if i.retweet_count != 0:
         print("this is a retweet")
    else:
         print(i.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

also if this doesn't work for you, just print out one of the i values completely (without text or other commands) and it'll show you all of the potential arguments you could use inside the dictionary